# or-tools Maximize/Minimize OR / XOR

Tags: optimization, or-tools

Simple example:

```py
days = range(1,10)
for d in days:
   model.AddBoolXOr(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
```

Above I can ensure only one of a...g is true every day. But it is not always possible to achieve this every day so I want to be able to maximize the number of times it is achieved. Something like...

```py
array_bools = []
days = range(1,10)
for d in days:
   day_bool = NewBoolVar('name')
   model.Add(day_bool = XOr(a,b,c,d,e,f,g))
   array_bools.append(day_bool)

model.Maximize(sum(array_bool[i] for i in range(len(array_bool))))
```

Comment: `xor(array of bool vars)` does no mean only one is true, it means an odd number of them is true.

Comment: Thanks Laurent. Even so... is it possible to maximize the number of days True is returned?

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Many thanks Laurent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_bools = []
days = range(1,10)
for d in days:
    day_bool = NewBoolVar('name')
    model.Add(sum([a,b,c,d,e,f,g]) == 1).OnlyEnforceIf(day_bool)
    model.Add(sum([a,b,c,d,e,f,g]) != 1).OnlyEnforceIf(day_bool.Not())
    array_bools.append(day_bool)

model.Maximize(sum(array_bool))
```

See [this page of documentation](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md)